# What can be the reason why Mail::send in Octobercms cuts the HTML tags from richeditor?

Tags: octobercms, octobercms-backend

I am using the Mail::send service to send an email from a contact form. The body of the email is HTML, provided with the richeditor. I have a template 'my.plugin::mail.default':

```
subject = "Overwritten"
==
<p>Hi {{ name }},</p>

{{message_body | raw}}

<p>This email was sent using formatting (HTML)</p>
```

and the code to send is like this:

```
$data=post();
$vars = [
 'subject' => $data['subject'],
 'message_body' =>$data['message'],
 'name'=>'STB '
];
Mail::send('my.plugin::mail.default', $vars, function ($message) use ($vars) {
 $message->to("reciever@email.com");
 $message->subject($vars['subject']);
});
```

Email sent this way has the HTML message striped and only **first tag** (ex: `<p>abc<p/>`) is sent.

After many test, I figured out that when the HTML has the new-line character `\n` (as var $html below), Mail::send sends the message correctly. However, when the HTML hasn't the new-line character (as var $html_richeditor below), then it is cut.

```
$html = '<p>Aenean finibus erat eget maximus luctus. Phasellus vitae lectus dolor. Morbi convallis ex et turpis porttitor mattis morbi convallis ex et turpis porttitor mattis</p>
                <p>Proin porta, nibh eget elementum aliquet, metus elit viverra nisi, vitae ullamcorper elit eros ut urna.</p>
                <br/><br><p>Morbi convallis ex et turpis porttitor mattis.</p>';

$html_richeditor = "<p>Aenean finibus erat eget maximus luctus. Phasellus vitae lectus dolor. Morbi convallis ex et turpis porttitor mattis morbi convallis ex et turpis porttitor mattis</p><p>Proin porta, nibh eget elementum aliquet, metus elit viverra nisi, vitae ullamcorper elit eros ut urna.</p><p><br></p><p><br></p><p>Morbi convallis ex et turpis porttitor mattis.</p>";
```

Any idea how I can send the whole HTML from the richeditor? Should I config something in the richeditor or in the Mail?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have debugged a lot and found out that HTML was parsed by `Markdown` and it was not linking that single line stuff and just keep the first `tag`.

> UPDATE - as per OctoberCMS 2.0 Docs

**It is important to note that the Markdown parser will only accept one HTML node per line.**

Ref: https://docs.octobercms.com/2.x/services/parser.html#using-html-in-markdown

So we need to make our HTML like one node per line. we can just append `\n` to all tag's ending `>` bracket so it will persist during `Markdown` parsing.

```php
$data=post();
$vars = [
 'subject' => $data['subject'],
 'message_body' => strtr($data['message'], ['>' => ">\n"]),
  // replacing `>` with `>\n` please use double quote with `\n`
 'name'=>'STB '
];
Mail::send('my.plugin::mail.default', $vars, function ($message) use ($vars) {
 $message->to("reciever@email.com");
 $message->subject($vars['subject']);
});
```

> OR as per @SamuelGeorges you can wrap your message within `<div>` tag.

> Now it should work as expected.

if any doubts please comment.

Comment: Yes, the workaround fixed it. Thank you @Hardik. It is however something that the OctoberCMS team should look at. I just used the basic setting as it is documented and here I spend several hours to try to fix it.

Comment: Yes sometimes it happens, But maybe it's because of some security reasons they did it, but anyways I am glad it fixed your issue :)

Comment: We've updated the documentation to include advice for working with HTML and Markdown: https://docs.octobercms.com/2.x/services/parser.html#using-html-in-markdown

Comment: @SamuelGeorges thanks for updating us, and huge thanks for giving us OctoberCMS :) also updated the answer and added document links and info.

Answer (score 4):

This is a quirk of the Markdown parser, when it sees two or more HTML nodes on the same line, it will only capture the first node (one node per line).

```
// Outputs: <p>hello</p>
<p>hello</p><p>yo</p>
```

To overcome this, one should tell Markdown that it should expect HTML by wrapping everything in a node as well.

```
// Outputs: <div><p>hello</p><p>yo</p></div> 
<div><p>hello</p><p>yo</p></div>
```

The solution is to wrap your raw HTML statement in a  tag.

```
<div>
    {{message_body|raw}}
</div>
```